# Django media files location on disk

Tags: django

I have a media folder `/media/` referenced by `settings.py` in

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/project_name/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

In `urls.py` I have this:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
```

When I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/media/` this is the accessible file structure:

```
media/
    images/
        2014/
            12/
                5/
                    <many files here>
                6/
                    <many files here>
```

Where exactly are these files? They are not in `media` folder in the project anymore. They were deleted hours ago. Actual file structure is like this:

```
media/
    images/
        2014/
            12/
                6/
                    <files here>
    thumbs/
        2014/
            12/
                6/
                    <files here>
```

Files in the two structures are not identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the media folder was located in `C:/project_name/media` and it was fetching from there instead of project's media folder.

I modified the code for url like this:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')+'/media/', 'show_indexes': True})
```

to remove any ambiguity about possible relative locations. I didn't know that django checked for data in `C:\` first instead of project's root folder.